# PHP Include Path. Can it always be from the root directory?

Tags: php

I'd like to reference files from the root directory even if, the file that is calling the new file, is in a directory itself. Possible?

*i.e. 

From within the /includesheader.php file:  include("/styles/style.css")

From within the reports/customers.php file :include("/reports/sales.php")*

**/Styles**
   style.css
**/Reports**
   sales.php
   customers.php
**/Includes**
   connection.php
   header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Leading `/` always refers to root

Comment: the answer is no? not possible? Does the / make the path relative to the root? I have tried that and keep getting an error. If i change to ../ it works, but then breaks as a file is being called from it's own directory and another directory, so i can't win both ways. :(

Comment: @jason3w: do you have a common file that is included by each script? If so - create `PROJECT_ROOT` constant there with the **absolute** path to the project root and use it after like: `include PROJECT_ROOT . '/reports/sales.php;`

Comment: sorry to be dumb and ask, but i do this at the top of each file: `code`<?php include("includes/connection.php"); ?> `code`. Do i always have to use the `code` ../ `code` at some point to at least load the constants.php, to then set the PROJECT_ROOT.

Comment: @jason3w: yes. That is why it is a common practice to forward all requests in a single file and route within your application

Comment: i think i just don't understand the basic concept. i thought / would mean go back to the root and work from there. but then realised that didn't work so started using ../ if in a folder. then run into trouble with conflicting paths when including from includes....

Comment: i've tried searching for info on this and read a bit so far, but no luck finding a clear answer.

Comment: @jason3w: clear answer for what? Leading `/` **always** refers to a system root. `../` refers to a parent directory for current

Comment: ok, that's clear. i thought root meant project root. thanks for your help.